# Meteor Idle CPU utilization is high

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor

I'm trying to set up my Meteor apps on AWS EB and I've successfully deployed 2. Weird thing is one of them is using 30% CPU when idle, as opposed to 0.3% on the other one.

Both are running `METEOR@1.4.2.3`, both are on t2.large EC2 instances. I previously had the apps on Galaxy without any issues (have to make the switch because we got a generous amount of credits from AWS)

The only difference is the app that's idle at 30% has Meteor settings be loaded on startup and the other one doesn't use any Meteor settings since it's just used to connect to the DB and display info (as a microservice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, was using Node version 6+ that isn't supported by Meteor fully yet, switching to 4.6.1 did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Are you issuing this

```
meteor build --server ${ROOT_URL} --verbose --directory ${BUILD_NODEJS_DIR} --mobile-settings build/${SETTINGS_JSON_FILE}
```

to bundle your code ready for deployment ... then over on your cloud provider are you executing your meteor app by calling

```
node main.js
```

This adheres to current meteor standards of deployment ( version 1.4.2.3 ) ... which I am using to deploy a meteor app onto AWS EC2 and see no high CPU usage when its idle

Comment: I am doing `meteor build --directory ../build/ --architecture os.linux.x86_64` as per https://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html#custom-deployment and then adding a package.json file with `node main.js` as the start script with some dependencies. Your build command is using some variables I haven't seen before. Can you further explain `--mobile-settings` and `--verbose` and if you have custom Meteor settings, how are you adding them to the environment. Thanks!